# issue while running andriod studio for flutter

Tags: flutter

I am unable to understand how to resolve this error. Can you help what i am missing. I am very new to flutter.
[image]

Comment: Check this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36517366/1003059

Answer (score 1):

If `gradle clean build` does not work for you, you might want to double check your android project settings. Open android folder within your flutter project in android studio; then open **File > Project Structure**. Then check that **Project SDK** has a value, should be something like **Android API 29 Platform**,

Comment: Yes, Path was not set properly for flutter. Once i did that it got resolved. Thanks for the answer