# How to remove Kotlin Support from Flutter App?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, kotlin

Created a new Flutter project with Kotlin support on Android Studio and it is giving the following error on running the app:-

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

Now I just want to remove the Kotlin support from my project, please suggest the steps?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980792/4712391. Use `flutter create -a java ` instead of the default to kotlin

Comment: Have you tried the solution I have given below? If you have faced any in that please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, there might be many reasons behind...
Check out this [Stack Overflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357507/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin/46366658) if this can work.
Apart from this, To remove Kotlin support you can check your Gradle for some lines below..

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

```
...
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...
android{
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    ...
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

Delete all of these above to remove kotlin support in your project.

Comment: Also, comment out any kotlin keyworded options: `// kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = '1.8' }`
and remember to add a `MainActivity.java` under main/java/ folder (with or without namespace dir structure) and delete kt folder:
`
package com.msheriff.kingdom;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity { }
`